# What is the meaning of "killing" when facing a difficult gaming level?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

My friend was playing a game, but it was to difficult to complete a level. But after so many tries, when she did, she said "Yayyy! I did it, this level was killing me!" What does "killing" mean here?

Comment: It was giving her a hard time.

Comment: That's a perfectly good answer.  Why did you post it as a comment?

Comment: So, something killing someone can also mean giving a hard time to someone?

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, it was a hard level and she kept trying it. That means at that time she was frustrated or *was going mad*.

> As stated in the comments also, killing me means if you are having a hard time or you had a hard time(past continuous tense)
>  
>   For ex. "This problem is killing" or in your case "it was killing me".

Comment: Can we use it for a person as well? E.g if a teacher is giving a hard time to a student, can we say "the teacher is killing me?

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem at all. Saying, *The teacher is killing me* is correct and moreover saying metaphors like this is a good way to express your feelings.